# Crash in Array index

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing ios app. Save data in Core Data and fetch data from core data. And data pass to array and counting the array but the problem is that app will crash Error msg is [reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array']. please giving me solution thanks in advance.

```
code..
    NSError *err = nil;
  _offlineResult = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
 NSLog(@"%@",_offlineResult);
 for (int i =0 ; i<[_offlineResult count]; i++) {
 NSDictionary *dic = [_offlineResult objectAtIndex:i];
 NSString *offlineChildProductId = [dic valueForKey:@"childproductid"];
                    if ([_offlineProductID isEqual:offlineChildProductId]) {
                        _productName.text = [dic valueForKey:@"baseproductcode"];
                        _productDescription.text = [dic valueForKey:@"baseproductdesc"];

                        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithData:[dic valueForKey:@"productimageone"]];
                    _imageFirst.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

CoreData managed object context is not thread-safe by default. The probable reason of your crash is, that the managed objects are getting deleted from your fetch operation(even if fetch is happening in a background thread).

You need to introduce **[concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html)** in the way you are saving the objects.

1. Create a child managed object context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.
2. Perform save operation in the performBlock of this managed object context.